# iOS: Good way to pass value from image button to func in the class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Initially I had two buttons with titles: "+" and "-". Both buttons are located in table cell. I have used protocol and delegate to pass value from button title to function call which depends on input params. If input parameter is "-" - decrease value, if "+" - increase.

But later I removed titles and replaced buttons with respective images. And here I faced an issue - I cannot call function properly because title is blank.

I have implemented the following workaround. I have set Accessibility Identifier for both buttons. For example for +:

[image]

And in cell class I used accessibilityIdentifier:

```
@IBAction func didPressOrderCellButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    cellDelegate?.didPressOrderCellButton(order: order!, menuItem: menuItem!, action: sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)
}
```

But... I have some doubts if it's proper way to do this. Will it create any issues in future if I decide to work with accessibility feature?
I do not want to use title and add code to ViewController class to hide it every time view is loaded or appeared. I want to avoid such solutions in my code because it's too difficult to support such solutions I believe.

I have tried to find another button identifier that I can use, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach would be just set the `tag` value inside your `button` and then check the same `tag` value and perform your operation `Plus` or `Minus` accordingly.

For instance:-

```
if sender.tag == 0 {
//Do minus
} else if sender.tag == 1 {
//Do plus
}
```

Comment: Looks like valid solution. But is there any other identifier with String type? Tags are okay, but allows using only integer values.

Comment: Other than tag there is only title where you can define the string but using tag is more reliable. Also accessibility identifier is use for automation testing purpose.

Comment: Thank you, Hussain! Appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Also title can be change in future but tag value will always remain constant.

Comment: Np, glad it helps:)